# Sum of Infinity of Trigo to Pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, pi

I am currently working on a proof with a good friend of mine that involves adding more and more triangles to the sides of a regular polygon but keeping the longest diagonal constant until eventually, it becomes a circle. And we ended up with this formula.

$4$-sided regular$ \to 8$-sided regular$\to 16$-sided regular$\to 32$-sided regular\to \ldots \to n$-sided regular

(When $n$ tends to infinity, the area will be equal to that of a circle with the longest diagonal as diameter)

Moreover, we have used our calculator to input the numbers and we get the value of $3.140\ldots$ which is very close to π But we can't be completely sure that the infinity sum really equals to π.

That is why we really need your knowledge of Maths to solve this.

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays Everyone! :D

**So the question is: 
Is there a way to legitly prove that**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n \left(2\cdot \sin\frac{90^\circ}{2^n}-\sin \frac{180^\circ}{2^n}\right)=\pi$$

(please kindly refer to Appendix 1)

P.S. I apologize for my poor penmanship...

P.P.S. We tried using Wolfram Alpha, it didn't show us the step-by-step calculations

[image]

Comment: No I don't you did, Siong, I think the initiate solution you gave that the expression is equal to zero is correct

Comment: But i am not sure how I ended up with the answer zero, as my original equation was set to be equal to pi... XD

Comment: i think you are considering the series rather than the sequence, i did misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Anyways can you repost your solution? Thank you in advance and Happy Holidays to you, Siong :D

Comment: Does my Summation n=1 + n=2 + ... converges to pi?

Comment: perhaps, the numerical value is closed but i m uncertain.

Comment: Thanks anyways XD

Comment: I don't understand what each of those summands mean.  Why do you say $\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k(2\sin\frac {90^\circ}{2^k}- \sin\frac {180^\circ}{2^k}) = $Area of a regular $2^n$-gon with longest diagonal equal to $2$?

Comment: This summation indeed converges to $\pi$ but is not a good choice for numerical computation as it takes square roots and converges slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^m 2^n \left(2 \sin \frac{90^\circ}{2^n} - \sin \frac{180^\circ}{2^n} \right) &=\sum_{n=0}^m 2^n \left(2 \sin \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} - \sin \frac{\pi}{2^n} \right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^m  \left(2^{n+1} \sin \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} - 2^n\sin \frac{\pi}{2^n} \right)\\
&=\left(2^1 \cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2} -2^0\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2^0}\right)\\
&+\left(2^2 \cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2^2} -2^1\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2^1}\right)\\
&+\left(2^3 \cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2^3} -2^2\cdot \sin \frac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\\
&\vdots\\
&+\left(2^{m+1} \sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}} - 2^m\sin \frac{\pi}{2^m} \right)\\
&= 2^{m+1}\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}-2^0 \sin \pi \\
&= 2^{m+1}\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}
\end{align}

Hence

\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n \left(2 \sin \frac{90^\circ}{2^n} - \sin \frac{180^\circ}{2^n} \right)&= \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^m 2^n \left(2 \sin \frac{90^\circ}{2^n} - \sin \frac{180^\circ}{2^n} \right) \\
&=\lim_{m \to \infty} 2^{m+1}\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}\\
&=\lim_{m \to \infty} 2^{m+1}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}\cdot \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}}\\
&=\lim_{m \to \infty} 2^{m+1}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}\cdot \lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}}\\
&= \pi \cdot 1\\
&= \pi\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, Siong! This is the full proof! :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\sin \frac{\pi}{2^n} = 2\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} \cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ and the fundamental limit for sine tells us that $\pi \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}} = \pi$. Try to do some algebraic manipulation to get those.

Comment: Thank you so much gonna work on that now! :D

Comment: It is, in fact, a telescopic form (i did some googling ;D)  I can cross out the terms and I get (-sin 180) remaining... what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The sum telescopes, as the general term is (in radians)

$$2^{n+1}\sin\frac\pi{2^{n+1}}-2^n\sin\frac\pi{2^{n}}.$$

So the sum between $0$ and $m$ is

$$2^{m+1}\sin\frac\pi{2^{m+1}}-\sin\pi=2^{m+1}\left(\frac\pi{2^{m+1}}+o\left(\frac1{2^{m+1}}\right)\right)$$

which converges to $\pi$.